# converting office documents to html5

Tags: html, ms-office

I am working on a project, and I need something like office web app , I don't know if I can make it myself , how to read office file formats and convert it to html5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very significant project to convert arbitrary Office documents to HTML 5.

Office itself can generally save in HTML format.  You can most likely use the Interop libraries provided by the various Office products to save as HTML.  Look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.saveas(v=office.11).aspx

If you want to do this from scratch (without using an existing implementation or the Interop libraries), you can look at the Open XML format

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I need to implement something like google docs , but I don't know where to start.

Comment: If you don't even know where to start, this is not a project which you are likely to be able to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Remember MS has developed solutions like Office 365 for Cloud. Also, you have Google Docs to "see" and (of course) edit documents online, but it has its limitations. For example, there may be problems with Excel macros and other advanced features.

What do you exactly want to? and What is the complexity level of your documents?

Comment: google docs is really good , but I need to implement it from scratch !!

Comment: take a look [here](http://mashable.com/2007/08/07/google-docs-api/)... and get excited [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/). Of course, take a look on StackOverflow for questions asked before.